# Aws MediaConvert - Create one output video file with a single audio track and multiple video inputs

Tags: amazon-web-services, video-encoding, aws-media-convert

I’m working with Aws MediaConvert in order to create video-files concatenation.
I'm able for now to create concatenation of *n* videos in one output mpeg4 file, with or without audio "**inside each video input**".

What i'm looking to achieve is to create the same but with one single audio track for the whole video that i would import and muting each video inputs audio if there are.
I don't know if MediaConvert allows that (not found my case in Aws MediaConvert Documentation).

I made a small schema representing what i'm trying to achieve :

[image]

I figured out i can do that with two jobs, one that will concatenate all my video input and mute their audios if there are. And the second one merging the single audio track in the result of the previous one.
This solution however doesn't feel to be the best one.

Do you know if can achieve what i'm trying to do in one job with Aws MediaConvert and if yes, which settings have I to tweak ?

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't think that is possible

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have look at this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/create-selectors.html), especially for the following part

> If your audio is in a separate file from your video, choose the External file slider switch element and provide the URI to your audio input file that is stored in Amazon S3 ...

By choosing audio from external file and set proper timestamp offset, maybe you can combine your two jobs to one.